# How can I access "socialaccount-socialaccount" table

Tags: python, json, django, django-allauth

Sorry for my english if I do a mistake. I am using django-allauth for social login in my django application. Django-allaouth is keep person's information data in "extra-data" attribute on "socialaccount-socialaccount" table. This is "extra-data" attribute.

```
{"timezone": 3, "first_name": "Kerim", "updated_time": "2016-04-18T13:03:38+0000", "name": "Kerim Fett", "gender": "male", "verified": false, "id": "141262349608745", "email": "kerim@yandex.com", "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/", "last_name": "Fett", "locale": "tr_TR"}
```

My question how can I access to "socialaccount-socialaccount" table attributes in views.py.

Comment: `extra-data` looks like a dictionary, how do you normally retrieve values from a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`extra_data` is a dictionary here. you can simply access with `key`

```
>>extra_data['gender']
"male"
>>extra_data.get('gender', None)
"male"
```

Comment: @Sayse can you elaborate?